Share CLI on Https web server
I have in /opt/example.sh that show me ip usage
Now my question is How share CLI in public for example https web server ?
for example server ubuntu by ip address 192.168.10.1
by putty see result of sh file
now in public in web server https://192.168.10.1 see result too
Thanks for help

If you like to share the result of a script which runs locally, you need to somehow implement a server with a programming language that a) is able to run external scripts, b) catch the output, c) build a website from it. This is possible with many common languages, e.g. PHP, Python, Go, Rust, ...

Have Any Tools on ubuntu that share CLI screen on web sever ????

I'm not aware of any. Which is good, as exposing CLI access to a computer via a web interface is a major safety concern. I understand you intention, but I feel like you are oversimplifying things.
I you are willing to put some work in into programming a solution yourself, I would suggest to start a thread at Stack Overflow, which is focussed on programming tasks.
